# How to make player instantly move to the right or left when entering a box collider

Tags: unity, c#

I have a box collider and right now when I walk into it it says "you can't go there yet" I would like it for it to also move the player like 3 steps to the right or something. How would I do thatr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided enough info, but I may have a solution.

You may have a `void Player::playAnimation` function in your 'player.cs' file for your PLAYER gameObject.

Go to the file where your controls for the player are. Read and understand the code. It should have this:

```
If (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Right) == true) {
  player.moveRight;
}
```

Now, `moveRight` is a function that moves the player right. This is perhaps the code for it:

```
void Player::moveRight() {
  animator.SetBool("MoveRight", true);
  GameObject.move(Vector3.right);
  _facing = RIGHT;
}
```

Now, you can simply apply this `playAnimation` logic here in your box gameObject (tagged here as 'box1'):

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll) { 
  string tag = coll.collider.gameObject.tag; 
  if (tag == "box1") { 
    player.moveRight; 
    } 
  }
```

Hope that helped.